# How to remove tabs "\n" and witespace from text?

Tags: regex, xml, groovy

I have a XML document and after every update  operation from code it has   some extra spaces and as a result file size increases. I used this  expression  in groovy, but it doesn't work. What should I do?

```
 def stringWriter = new StringWriter()
 new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(stringWriter)).print(xml)
 def newXml = stringWriter.toString()
 String trimmedString = newXml.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "");
 println trimmedString
```

Comment: Check  the update operation and fix it. That will be a solution. What are you are doing now is looking for a work around.

Comment: Do   you  think  that   there  is  something  bad  with  my  update   logic  that's  why  i  can't  get  rid   of  tabs?